# DNS cache: systemd-resolve and ping resolve different IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, ping, dns-hosting, systemd-resolve

I have changed the IP address in a DNS record (on Google Cloud DNS), associated to a subdomain *test.example.com*

From my Google Cloud VM:

- if I `ping test.example.com`, I get the old IP address
- if I `systemd-resolve test.example.com`, I get the new IP address

I have tried to flush the DNS cache using:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

but **ping** is still getting the old IP address

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in /etc/resolve.conf and where is it pointing to (if symlink)? What's in the `hosts:` line in /etc.nsswitch.conf?

Comment: this is the default for Google Cloud Compute virtual machines:
`resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`
"hosts:" in nsswitch.conf says "files dns"

Comment: content of resolv.conf:
`nameserver 127.0.0.53`
`options edns0 trust-ad`
`search c.myproject.internal google.internal`

Comment: Do you have by any chance this name in /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Which name do you mean?

Comment: What distribution and version of linux you are running ? Did you restart your VM after obseved difference in IP's ? Did you do any network configuration on your network settings or installed any network related software that may have done this ? Please provide more information about your setup so we can troubleshoot this.

Comment: @DanieleB, do you have test.example.com in /etc/hosts?

Comment: I am using the default configuration on the VM, which is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Google Cloud. I tried to restart the VM, but nothing changed.

Comment: tesr.example.con is not in /etc/hosts

Comment: To clarify, now after many hours, the IP is shown correctly also for ping. But still isn't clear why ping was resolving a different IP than systemd-resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Behavior you observed comes from a [known `systemd` bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320) - I dare to say that since you [indicated](https://serverfault.com/questions/1094557/dns-cache-systemd-resolve-and-ping-resolve-different-ip-addresses#comment1428489_1094557) that you have `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` - `systemd` adds it due to mentioned bug. Have a look at the answers provided since they may contain a solution that's right for you. Most of them however suggest to "hardcode" DNS.

**Ping works in a different way and it was able to resolve the name correctly.**

Inner workings related to DNS and `systemd-resolve` were [discussed at length here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager).